# Tensor is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, memory-leaks, neural-network

I'm getting this error

> 'ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=int32)
>   is not an element of this graph.'

The code is running perfectly fine without `with tf.Graph(). as_default():`. However I need to call `M.sample(...)` multiple times and each time the memory won't be free after `session.close()`. Probably there is a memory leak but not sure where is it.

I want to restore a pre-trained neural network, set it as default graph, and testing it multiple times (like 10000) over the default graph without making it larger each time.

The code is:

```
def SessionOpener(save):
    grph = tf.get_default_graph()
    sess = tf.Session(graph=grph)
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(save)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./predictor/save/model.ckpt.meta')
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
    return sess

def LoadPredictor(save):
    with open(os.path.join(save, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = cPickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(save, 'words_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        words, vocab = cPickle.load(f)
    model = Model(saved_args, True)
    return model, words, vocab

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Save = './save'
    M, W, V = LoadPredictor(Save)
    Sess = SessionOpener(Save)
    word = M.sample(Sess, W, V, 1, str(123), 2, 1, 4)
    Sess.close()
```

And the model is:

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self, args, infer=False):
        with tf.Graph().as_default():
            self.args = args
            if infer:
                args.batch_size = 1
                args.seq_length = 1

            if args.model == 'rnn':
                cell_fn = rnn.BasicRNNCell
            elif args.model == 'gru':
                cell_fn = rnn.GRUCell
            elif args.model == 'lstm':
                cell_fn = rnn.BasicLSTMCell
            else:
                raise Exception("model type not supported: {}".format(args.model))

            cells = []
            for _ in range(args.num_layers):
                cell = cell_fn(args.rnn_size)
                cells.append(cell)

            self.cell = cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)

            self.input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, args.seq_length])
            self.targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, args.seq_length])
            self.initial_state = cell.zero_state(args.batch_size, tf.float32)
            self.batch_pointer = tf.Variable(0, name="batch_pointer", trainable=False, dtype=tf.int32)
            self.inc_batch_pointer_op = tf.assign(self.batch_pointer, self.batch_pointer + 1)
            self.epoch_pointer = tf.Variable(0, name="epoch_pointer", trainable=False)
            self.batch_time = tf.Variable(0.0, name="batch_time", trainable=False)
            tf.summary.scalar("time_batch", self.batch_time)

            def variable_summaries(var):
            """Attach a lot of summaries to a Tensor (for TensorBoard visualization)."""
                with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
                    mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
                    tf.summary.scalar('mean', mean)
                    tf.summary.scalar('max', tf.reduce_max(var))
                    tf.summary.scalar('min', tf.reduce_min(var))


            with tf.variable_scope('rnnlm'):
                softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [args.rnn_size, args.vocab_size])
                variable_summaries(softmax_w)
                softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [args.vocab_size])
                variable_summaries(softmax_b)
                with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
                    embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [args.vocab_size, args.rnn_size])
                    inputs = tf.split(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.input_data), args.seq_length, 1)
                    inputs = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) for input_ in inputs]

            def loop(prev, _):
                prev = tf.matmul(prev, softmax_w) + softmax_b
                prev_symbol = tf.stop_gradient(tf.argmax(prev, 1))
                return tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, prev_symbol)

            outputs, last_state = legacy_seq2seq.rnn_decoder(inputs, self.initial_state, cell, loop_function=loop if infer else None, scope='rnnlm')
            output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(outputs, 1), [-1, args.rnn_size])
            self.logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
            self.probs = tf.nn.softmax(self.logits)
            loss = legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([self.logits],
                    [tf.reshape(self.targets, [-1])],
                    [tf.ones([args.batch_size * args.seq_length])],
                    args.vocab_size)
            self.cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / args.batch_size / args.seq_length
            tf.summary.scalar("cost", self.cost)
            self.final_state = last_state
            self.lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
            tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
            grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars),
                args.grad_clip)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr)
            self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars))

    def sample(self, sess, words, vocab, num=200, prime='first all', sampling_type=1, pick=0, width=4):
        def weighted_pick(weights):
            t = np.cumsum(weights)
            s = np.sum(weights)
            return(int(np.searchsorted(t, np.random.rand(1)*s)))

        ret = ''
        if pick == 1:
            state = sess.run(self.cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32))

            if not len(prime) or prime == ' ':
                prime  = random.choice(list(vocab.keys()))
            for word in prime.split()[:-1]:
                x = np.zeros((1, 1))
                x[0, 0] = vocab.get(word,0)
                feed = {self.input_data: x, self.initial_state:state}
                [state] = sess.run([self.final_state], feed)

            ret = prime
            word = prime.split()[-1]
            for n in range(num):
                x = np.zeros((1, 1))
                x[0, 0] = vocab.get(word, 0)
                feed = {self.input_data: x, self.initial_state:state}
                [probs, state] = sess.run([self.probs, self.final_state], feed)
                p = probs[0]

                if sampling_type == 0:
                    sample = np.argmax(p)
                elif sampling_type == 2:
                    if word == '\n':
                        sample = weighted_pick(p)
                    else:
                        sample = np.argmax(p)
                else: # sampling_type == 1 default:
                    sample = weighted_pick(p)

                ret = words[sample]
        return ret
```

and the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/rcg/software/Linux/Ubuntu/16.04/amd64/TOOLS/TENSORFLOW/1.2.1-GPU-PY352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 942, in _run
    allow_operation=False)
  File "/rcg/software/Linux/Ubuntu/16.04/amd64/TOOLS/TENSORFLOW/1.2.1-GPU-PY352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2584, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/rcg/software/Linux/Ubuntu/16.04/amd64/TOOLS/TENSORFLOW/1.2.1-GPU-PY352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2663, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=int32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you create a `Model`, the session hasn't been restored yet. All placeholders, variables and ops that are defined in `Model.__init__` are placed in a *new graph*, which makes itself a default graph inside `with` block. This is the key line:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  ...
```

This means that this instance of `tf.Graph()` equals to `tf.get_default_graph()` instance inside `with` block, **but not before or after it**. From this moment on, there exist two different graphs.

When you later create a session and restore a graph into it, you can't access the previous instance of `tf.Graph()` in that session. Here's a short example:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
  var = tf.get_variable("var", shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

# This works
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(var))  # ok because `sess.graph == graph`

# This fails
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/model.ckpt.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print(sess.run(var))   # var is from `graph`, not `sess.graph`!
```

The best way to deal with this is give names to all nodes, e.g. `'input'`, `'target'`, etc, save the model and then look up the nodes in the *restored* graph by name, something like this:

```py
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/model.ckpt.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")      
  input_data = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input')
  target = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('target')
```

This method guarantees that all nodes will be from the graph in session.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. Apparently I can't rate your answer yet.

Comment: Hi, I got the same error when predicting. This https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14356#issuecomment-389606499 solved my problem. I put clear_session() before return statement in predict method.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. In my case although the tf.graph had same placeholder names it would still fail. Using `sess.graph` works.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this issue, none of the proposed solutions worked for me. This was the one working in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74104235/6713310

Answer (score 24):

Try first:

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

Then, when you need to use predict:

```
with graph.as_default():
     y = model.predict(X)
```

Comment: This worked well for me. Other methods are also reported here. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling the python function that calls Tensorflow from an external module, make sure that you the model isn't being loaded as a global variable or else it may not be loaded in time for usage. This happened to me calling a Tensorflow model from the Flask server.

Comment: I encountered same problem in the Flask. How did you handled it? Not loading as global variable means: every function in which Tensorflow is used should be imported inside the function? Is this the way you do?

Comment: @Ceyhun I moved the model load into the function being called because that was the only function it was used in. You could pass the model from function to function if you are using it for multiple functions and only want to load it once. The model I used was relatively small but if it's a large model you probably don't want to keep loading it, especially if you are doing any active learning.

Comment: I got your solution but this does not solved my problem. I used threading to seperate processes, also this did not solved my solution. I read more about this, Tensorflow processes don't work isolated, just run sequential and interfere each other. So I solved my solution using subprocess module calling python script for each function process. This is a bad solution I know, but I have this right now. Thanks anyway @colby-ham .

Comment: @Ceyhun Good to know about Tensorflow and threading. Probably a stupid question but did you try using multiprocessing? It's a cleaner solution than spawning subprocesses explicitly. I'm gonna take a dive into the docs for my own personal learning since you got me curious now.

Comment: No I did not use multiprocessing however I used threading.Lock. It also didn't solve my problem. I thought In my problem where should I put Lock in my code. If I put lock to training part, It's not different than sequential single thread. May be I'm wrong but I thought that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line before making models:

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

This will make a new graph to use in new models.

Comment: I am using tf 1.x, and when I clear the session, it worked for me.
But for TF 2.x this problem won't come.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was resolved by using Keras' APIs to save and load model. I had more than one models being trained in my code and I had to use the particular model for prediction under a condition.

So I saved the entire model to a HDF5 file after model training

```
# The '.h5' extension indicates that the model should be saved to HDF5.
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

and then recreate/reload the saved model at the time of prediction

```
my_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
```

This helped me get rid of

```
*Tensor not an element of this graph*
```

error.

Answer (score 0):

Inside
`def LoadPredictor(save):`

Just after loading the model, add `model._make_predict_function()`

So the function becomes:

```
def LoadPredictor(save):
    with open(os.path.join(save, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = cPickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(save, 'words_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        words, vocab = cPickle.load(f)
    model = Model(saved_args, True)
    model._make_predict_function()
    return model, words, vocab
```

Comment: add more explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to make a model using another class that uses keras to create a model. I got this issue corrected by doing the following

```
import nn_classifierclass as cls
from keras import backend
for repeat in range(repeats):
    backend.clear_session() ##NOTICE THIS
    neural_net = cls.Classifier(.....)
    neural_net.keras_fcn_classifier()
```