# How to test a trained model in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a trained TensorFlow model. The `data`, `index`, and `meta` files are all saved in a directory called `chkpt`. What I'm trying to achieve is to load the saved model and then run a single input through it to see the predicted class. I've tried a few different approaches with this, but nothing seems to work.

```
# Returns Tensor(1, 64, 64, 3 (float32)) and Tensor(1 (int32))
X, Y = get_data()  

x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 64, 64, 3]) 

tf.reset_default_graph()
meta = tf.train.import_meta_graph('chkpt/my_tf_model.meta')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    meta.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./chkpt/')
    print(sess.run(Y, feed_dict={x_placeholder: X))
```

With the above code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(1, 64, 64, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I've tried different arguments and approaches, but every time I hit a dead end. I'm not sure if there's a small mistake I'm making or my approach is totally off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensor is not an element of this graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115946/tensor-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph)

Comment: Have you looked at tf.Saver()?

Comment: @EvanWeissburg Yeah, I used tf.Saver() to save the model which I am loading with import_meta_graph()

Comment: Why not load it with restore? 
latest_ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(hparams.model_dir)
model.saver.restore(sess, latest_ckpt)