# ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

First of all, English is not my mother language so excuse me, if I don't express myself really well, please feel free to correct me.

I'm making an emotion recognition system that uses rest services to send the image from the client's browser.

This is the code:

```
# hyper-parameters for bounding boxes shape
frame_window = 10
emotion_offsets = (20, 40)

# loading models
face_detection = load_detection_model(detection_model_path)
emotion_classifier = load_model(emotion_model_path, compile=False)
K.clear_session()

# getting input model shapes for inference
emotion_target_size = emotion_classifier.input_shape[1:3]

# starting lists for calculating modes
emotion_window = []
```

And the function:

```
def detect_emotion(self, img):

    # Convert RGB to BGR
    bgr_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    faces = detect_faces(face_detection, gray_image)

    for face_coordinates in faces:

        x1, x2, y1, y2 = apply_offsets(face_coordinates, emotion_offsets)
        gray_face = gray_image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        try:
            gray_face = cv2.resize(gray_face, (emotion_target_size))
        except:
            continue

        gray_face = preprocess_input(gray_face, True)
        gray_face = np.expand_dims(gray_face, 0)
        gray_face = np.expand_dims(gray_face, -1)
        emotion_classifier._make_predict_function()

        emotion_prediction = emotion_classifier.predict(gray_face)

        emotion_probability = np.max(emotion_prediction)
        emotion_label_arg = np.argmax(emotion_prediction)
        emotion_text = emotion_labels[emotion_label_arg]
        emotion_window.append(emotion_text)

        if len(emotion_window) > frame_window:
            emotion_window.pop(0)
        try:
            emotion_mode = mode(emotion_window)
        except:
            continue

        if emotion_text == 'angry':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((255, 0, 0))
        elif emotion_text == 'sad':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((0, 0, 255))
        elif emotion_text == 'happy':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((255, 255, 0))
        elif emotion_text == 'surprise':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((0, 255, 255))
        else:
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((0, 255, 0))

        color = color.astype(int)
        color = color.tolist()

        draw_bounding_box(face_coordinates, rgb_image, color)
        draw_text(face_coordinates, rgb_image, emotion_mode,
                  color, 0, -45, 1, 1)

    img = Image.fromarray(rgb_image)

    return img


I'm facing this error when i run my code using waitress:

    File "c:\users\afgir\documents\pythonprojects\face_reco\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3569, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj) 
    ValueError: Tensor Tensor("predictions_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 7), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

It loads the image and does all the processing well, I'm pretty sure that the error is in the `emotion_classifier.predict` line, just don't know how to fix it.

I've tried with the two solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115946/tensor-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph) and none of them worked.

I'm really new using `Tensorflow` so I'm kinda stuck with this.

Comment: why do you use tf.Graph()?

Comment: It was a "Solution" that i found in a GitHub forum, but it didn't work neither.

Comment: See my answer, please comment if I would miss something

Answer (score 1):

I'm just trying to find out your real environment, but I guess you may use `Keras` amd some **Keras model** to predict emotions.

Your error message caused because of the line:

```
K.clear_session()
```

which, from the documentation: [keras.backend.clear_session()](http://%20tf.keras.backend.clear_session).
So you clear all graph it has been created, then you try to run the classifier's `predict()`, which lost all its context this way.
Thus just simply delete this line.

This section is was about some code the Op deleted:
In this task you don't need to use `tf.Graph()` at all. You just simply should call `emotion_classifier.predict()` as a simple python method **outside** and **without** of using any `tensorflow graph`:

```
def detect_emotion(self, img):

    # Convert RGB to BGR
    bgr_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    faces = detect_faces(face_detection, gray_image)

    for face_coordinates in faces:

        x1, x2, y1, y2 = apply_offsets(face_coordinates, emotion_offsets)
        gray_face = gray_image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        try:
            gray_face = cv2.resize(gray_face, (emotion_target_size))
        except:
            continue

        gray_face = preprocess_input(gray_face, True)
        gray_face = np.expand_dims(gray_face, 0)
        gray_face = np.expand_dims(gray_face, -1)
        emotion_classifier._make_predict_function()

        emotion_prediction = emotion_classifier.predict(gray_face)

        emotion_probability = np.max(emotion_prediction)
        emotion_label_arg = np.argmax(emotion_prediction)
        emotion_text = emotion_labels[emotion_label_arg]
        emotion_window.append(emotion_text)

        if len(emotion_window) > frame_window:
            emotion_window.pop(0)
        try:
            emotion_mode = mode(emotion_window)
        except:
            continue

        if emotion_text == 'angry':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((255, 0, 0))
        elif emotion_text == 'sad':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((0, 0, 255))
        elif emotion_text == 'happy':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((255, 255, 0))
        elif emotion_text == 'surprise':
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((0, 255, 255))
        else:
            color = emotion_probability * np.asarray((0, 255, 0))

        color = color.astype(int)
        color = color.tolist()

        draw_bounding_box(face_coordinates, rgb_image, color)
        draw_text(face_coordinates, rgb_image, emotion_mode,
                  color, 0, -45, 1, 1)

    img = Image.fromarray(rgb_image)

    return img
```

Comment: In the moment it detects a face, totally freezes and throws the same error, i'm using real time video streaming and when it receives the first image with a face in it, crashes.

Comment: @AndrésGirón first try to pass a single image to the predict function and see what happens and please reload the kernel to be sure. Simply you can't get the same error message

Comment: How do I reload the kernel?

Comment: @AndrésGirón did you restart the wsgi server or did it update your edited app? If yes, just simply try again please and pass one picture to the predict function.

Comment: I tried with a single image re-running the server and stills the same error. :(

Comment: @AndrésGirón Ok Andres, I will dive a bit deeper in the object trying to help you.

Comment: @AndrésGirón to being able to help on, please, revert your original code into your question and please provide the link to the `emotion_model_path` and `detection_model_path` or to the models they represent.

Comment: Hi. these are the links to the [emotion_model_path](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nv6V2w1cL1jeAdO93iKMNIsl2ZSUcJiy) and the [detection_model_path](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i-ao3FcqoNkr3ku3-yihLPgv1e2NyVzT) actually is weird when i'm using the `detection_model` alone, the service works perfectly, but when I'm using the `emotion_model` and the `predict` it's when everything crashes.

Comment: @AndrésGirón Ok. Andrés I will be back soon, hopefully with the solution.

Comment: @AndrésGirón I had to download a lot of dependencies to be able to test your code, but anyway success now, see my answer.

Comment: It didn't work, stills the same error using tensorflow backend, but I changed the backend to Theano to test, it actually worked, but really slow, almost unusable, so I wanna keep trying with Tensorflow. I can give you access to the git repository where the project is

Comment: @AndrésGirón it is strange, as I managed to get the predicted test image with the prediction labels, like "happy" etc.. Well give me the access to your project and I fix the problem over there too foe sure.

Comment: Hi. Have you been able to find any solution?

Comment: @AndrésGirón sry I am too busy these days, but today I will do it.

Comment: @AndrésGirón check gitlab

Comment: I keep getting the same error when I run it as web service

Comment: @AndrésGirón As you see I can't reproduce the error, as it works fine for me, when I run the code as simple python file. So the error is not from the code itself, but possibly some flask application/tensorflow context problem. Currently I did everything I can't see how can I reproduce exactly the same environment that causes the error, though if you want me to try help further you have to accurately describe the full environment in which the python app runs and exactly the process of running the code and other part of app and web-server tasks.

Comment: Hi. I'm running it on a Pyton 3.6.6 Environment, to run the code via web service, enter to the `/src/webII` folder using the terminal and run the command `waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 app:app`, that's how i'm getting the error, inside the same folder is the makeup_artist.py file where the CV logic is.

Comment: @AndrésGirón check Gitlab pls and replay THERE