# ValueError: Tensor Tensor("time_distributed_1/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, ?, 23), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, flask, keras, deep-learning

Getting this error of tensorflow dimension while calling the api from post man but runs perfectly when I run the function with no api call.
eg:

I have this api made in flask:

```
def main_function():
    round2 =clean_text_round2(my_text)
    round3 = str(Punctuation(round2))

    -------
    test = json.dumps(somejsonformat)
    return test
```

and my api is

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def padd():
    main_function()
app.run()
```

throws this error:
getting this error of tensorflow dimension while calling the api from post man but runs perfectly when i run the function with no api call.

But,
when I don't return the json data from the function
then it gives me result as i wanted.The code is
test = json.dumps(somejsonformat)

This test is JSON data 
and when I return it through api 
like this:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def padd():
    return test
app.run()
```

It gives me data in json format as belows:

```
array:22 [▼
  "edates" => array:21 [▶]
  "edate_tag" => array:21 [▶]
  "locations" => array:12 [▶]
  "location_tag" => array:12 [▶]
  "emails" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Sameera.itops@gmail.com"
    1 => "https://www.linkedin.com/in/sameera-cherukuri-888589150/"
  ]
  "emails_tag" => array:2 [▶]
  "cdates" => []
  "cdates_tag" => []
]
```

But I get above mention error while I return the json data (test)
through the function and calling it through api function padd().

It would be great help if someone could help me out on this issues.

Comment: Where is the Keras model? Where do you use the model?

Comment: its outside of the api call function.eg:   from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers.merge import add
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed,

Comment: I don't understand. Somewhere in your code, you must load and use the model, for example its `predict` function. Where is it? Do you load a pre-trained model? How is the api call (`padd()`) related to the model?

Comment: i have mailed you ...where can i share my full code so that you could get more ...please would you mind checking the mail

Comment: You can use a Github repository or gist to make your code publicly available. Further, it's better to edit your question and add more details there so that others having the same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it duplicate with this.

[Tensor is not an element of this graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115946/tensor-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph)

Something like this should work.

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def padd():
    with graph.as_default():
        main_function()  # contains model.predict
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, It really solved my problem