# My flask app is not reading the input images

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have created an Image Classifier Flask App but it doesn't read my input images(none of them). I have tried every solution I found on internet but couldn't solve my problem.

Below is Flask API I'm using:

```
@app.route('/upload',methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_analyze():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if a file was passed into the POST request
        if 'image' not in request.files:
            flash('No file was uploaded.')
            return redirect(request.url)


        image_file = request.files['image']
        #print(image_file)
        image_file = str(image_file)
        image = cv2.imread(image_file)

        clt = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
        dataset = pd.read_csv('bb22.csv') 
        X = dataset.iloc[:, 1: 8].values
        sc = StandardScaler()
        global orig , r
            # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
        #images = np.array(Image.open(image_file))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
        ................
```

It takes an input image of grain and calculates its length,width and tells whether its whole(1)/broken(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_file_uploading.htm) flask file uploading example code online.

I think the problem in your code is the return value from `request.files['image']` is an object that has methods like `save()` and `filename()`. `cv2.imread()` needs a file as an input so `str(image_file)` doesn't work.

Check out the example in the link above to see how the return value is used to save the file:

```
f = request.files['file']
filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
f.save(filename)
image = cv2.imread(filename)
```

Comment: .@Emrah Diril I have tried it,it just uploads the image but doesn't read it for image processing......

Comment: You need to save the uploaded image somewhere, then provide the path of that file to `cv2.imread`. I modified my answer to make that point clearer

Comment: now this error is coming: `ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`  still  not working:/

Comment: it is the code after `cv2.imread` that throws the error..I cant get it because it gave no error when I ran the code through command line..but it doesn't work through Flask.......

Comment: It sounds like your original question is answered. Please mark the answer as such and consider creating a new question with the new error. There might already be answers on SO, see this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115946

Comment: Your answer solved my issue but today again its giving the same error even though everything else is fine in the code ,I didn't even change anything :/

Comment: The problem probably has to do with `global orig , r`. Flask uses threads to process each request (like to display a page). It's not a good idea to use global variables because multiple threads will be accessing them potentially at the same time.

Comment: I figured out the problem ,it was occurring because after processing the image was getting emptied..i sorted it out thanks..