# ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1025), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Today I suddenly started getting this error for no apparent reason, while I was running `model.fit()`. This used to work before, I am using TF 2.3.0, more specifically its Keras module.
The function is called on validation inside a generator, which is fed into `model.predict()`.

Basically, I load a checkpoint, I resume training the network, and I make a prediction on validation.

The error keeps occurring even when training a model from scratch, and erasing all the related data. It's like if something has been hardcoded, somewhere, as I was able to run `model.fit()` up until a few hours ago.

I saw several solutions like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467697/6713310), but none of these variations really work for me, as they lead to more tricky error messages.

I even tried installing a different version of TF, thinking that this was due to some old version, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question, as this one was particularly tricky and none of the solutions I found on the internet has worked for me, probably because outdated.

I'll write down just the relevant part to add in the code, feel free to add more technical explanations.
I like using `args` for passing variables, but it can work without:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import generator # custom generator

def main(args):
   
   # open new session and define TF graph
   args.sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
   args.graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
   set_session(args.sess)

   # define training generator
   train_generator = generator(args.train_data)

   # load model
   args.model = load_model(args.model_path)
   args.model.fit(train_generator)
```

Then, in the model prediction function:

```
# In my specific case, the predict_output() function is 
# called inside the generator function
def predict_output(args, x):
    with args.graph.as_default():
        set_session(args.sess)
        y = model.predict(x)

    return y
```